# Function template overload resolution fails in Visual C++ 2017

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++14

I am trying to figure out if what I wrote is legal C++14 w.r.t. unambiguous function template overload resolution.

In my opinion, the below program should compile and return `3`.

Various versions of Clang and GCC compute just that at compile time (using `-std=c++14 -O2`), but Visual C++ 2017 (Version 15.5.2; latest update at time of writing) chokes on it with the below error message.

```
enum class Enum0 { State };
enum class Enum1 { State };

template <Enum0 Param0 = Enum0::State>
int get()
{
    return 1;
}

template <Enum1 Param1>
int get()
{
    return 2;
}

int main()
{
  int sum = 0;
  sum += get(); // should call instantiation of first function template
  sum += get<Enum1::State>(); // should call instantiation of second function template
  return sum;
}
```

This is the emitted error message by the Visual C++ compiler:

```
20 : <source>(20): error C2668: 'get': ambiguous call to overloaded function
11 : <source>(11): note: could be 'int get<Enum1::State>(void)'
5 : <source>(5): note: or       'int get<Enum0::State>(void)'
20 : <source>(20): note: while trying to match the argument list '()'
```

See https://godbolt.org/g/PhH2VY for a live demonstration (and https://godbolt.org/g/BVEv79 for the previous code example before editing the question).
Change the compiler to MVSC to see the compilation failing. GCC and Clang do not indicate any issue. Both nicely emit the following x86 assembly:

```
        mov     eax, 3
        ret
```

Are GCC and Clang too lenient, or is this an issue with Visual C++?

Comment: This sounds like something to ask at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

Comment: Sure. Once it's halfway established that this is indeed legal C++14 and supposed to compile, I will do that anyway.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your problem has nothing to do with the third case and the first two can be reduced. Why don't you provide a [mcve]

Comment: Way to be helpful! My given example was complete, verifiable and almost minimal. Indeed, the third function template and call could be removed, together with the enable_if<>. I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question, isn't it.  If I change the second call to get with:

```
sum += get<Enum1::State, int>(0.0); // should call instantiation of second function template
```

... then it compiles...

Notice, I add a second template argument. In my day to day work, I use an old dialect of C++ compatible with MFC...so take my reasoning with a grain of salt.  But, since you are only providing one argument to the template, and the second template requires two arguments, ISTM that the VC++ compiler is trying to use the first template because it has default arguments and can take only one argument. So it chooses that template but cannot do the conversion from Enum1 to Enum0.

Comment: That may be, but the whole point of this kind of API (in both my real code and this toy example) is to *not* have to type out all template parameters, but to be able to use either one or the other or both. Again `Enum0` and `Enum1` are distinct types, so there should be no ambiguity during argument deduction/overload resolution.